# find sum of value with the same ID with condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the salary table

```
COMPANY_ID  |   Salary  |  
========================= 
     1      |   20000   |
     2      |   10000   |
     3      |   50000   |
     4      |   13000   |
     2      |   8000    |
     3      |   20000   |
     5      |   20000   |
     1      |   10000   |
     4      |   40000   |
```

This is the company table

```
     ID     |   Comapny |  
========================= 
     1      |   Apple   |
     2      |  Facebook |
     3      |   Google  |
     4      | Microsoft |
     5      |   Oracle  |
```

my expected output is to find companies that has a average salary > 20000.

```
Google
Microsoft
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.  Where do you have a problem?

Comment: `SELECT  COMPANY_ID, avg(SALARY) FROM test.salary group by COMPANY_ID`

how do i put the condition in place where avg(salary) only show if its >20000?

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: In the `company` table, your column `Salary` has weird value.

Comment: @Eric Sorry, typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select company_name ,avg(tblSalary.salary) average_salary
from tblCompany
Inner join tblSalary on tblcompany.id = tblsalary.company_id
group by company_name 
having avg(tblSalary.salary) > 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select company from company a, salary b where a.id = b.id and b.salary >= 20000 group by a.company
```

or

```
select company from company a inner join salary b on a.id = b.id and b.salary  >= 20000 group by a.company
```

Like others said read your book, this is as basic as it gets.

Comment: the part i don't understand is that since the table shows Company_ID Occurring twice, meaning that it should only show the company if the avg(salary) combined is >20000